# In Apple Core Audio, how inUseCache parameters works

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio

In Apple Core Audio, we have the inUseCache parameter required in a lot of commands, but always I see that receiving false in example out there. How that works and how can I extract benefits from it to my applications?

Example functions which receives inUseCache

- AudioFileWriteBytes
- AudioFileReadPacketData
- AudioFileReadPackets
- AudioFileWritePackets